# Spaces in a joined array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been working on a ceaser cipher algorithm but I haven't been able to grasp the reason why the joined array returns spaces in a peculiar state.

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var string = str.split('');

  var codedStr = [];

  var encoded = [];
  for (var k=0; k < string.length; k++){
    codedStr.push(string[k].charCodeAt()); 
  }
  for(var i = 0; i < codedStr.length; i++){
    if(codedStr[i] > 77 ){
      codedStr[i] -= 13;
    } 
    else if( codedStr[i] == 32 || codedStr[i] == 63){
      codedStr[i] = codedStr[i];
    }

    else{
      codedStr[i] += 13;
    }
    encoded.push(codedStr[i]);
  }
  var decode = codedStr.map(String.fromCharCode);
  var result = decode.join('');
  return result;
}

// Change the inputs below to test
console.log(rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"));
```

Comment: Take a debugger and debug your code.

Answer (score 2):

`String.fromCharCode` accepts multiple arguments, and `map` provides 3. You should use

```
codedStr.map(code => String.fromCharCode(code));
```

Comment: This has solved my problem. I couldn't understand why it was spitting out more spaces.